# Безопасные потоки sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Не нашел в интернете нормального материала по многопоточности в sqlite3. Где-то пишут, что нельзя, а где-то, что можно с помощью аргумента в конструкторе. Просто не очень представляю как можно реализовать нормальную работу бота с базой данных используя PyTelegramBotAPI который мультипоточный. Как избежать проблем с общением с бд?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: Я так через peewee работал многопоточно с sqlite через класс SqliteQueueDatabase. Там суть в том, что select'ы тот выполняется напрямую, а insert/update/... через очередь, так изменение базы выполняется синхронно, пример из телеграм бота: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/004b4345c96aad289b21cc6f5d22017abd75d790/db.py#L41